# Joint Entropy of two time series

Tags: time-series, joint-distribution, entropy

I have two time series of same length like following:

```
X=[ 1.1833
    1.1467
    1.1767
    1.1833
    1.1000
    1.2367
    1.1633
    1.2100
    1.1200
    1.1800 ]
```

and

```
Y=[ 1.2067
    1.1800
    1.1400
    1.1900
    1.1467
    1.1467
    1.2167
    1.1967
    1.1633
    1.1300 ]
```

I want to calculate Joint Entropy of X and Y. I know the formula for H(x,y), but I am facing problem while calculating Joint probability.